# What word fits the sentence: 'it was proven with great _______'?

Tags: single-word-requests

The word I'm looking for would suggest that the thing in question was shown to be true even to the point of excess, and its veracity tested on multiple occasions or very publicly, so that there can be no residual doubt.

e.g.

> 'it was proven with great _______ that her methods were ineffective'

I've tried looking up synonyms for 'thoroughly' and 'excessively' which didn't turn it up. The word is right on the tip of my tongue and it's been bugging me for ages.

Comment: "rigor" -------

Comment: The way the sentence is set up, I can only think of "gusto."

Comment: Consider [accuracy and precision](https://labwrite.ncsu.edu/Experimental%20Design/accuracyprecision.htm).

Comment: @Showsni 'gusto' is actually the closest I've seen so far. Thought my word could've been a synonym but sadly not.

Comment: This could literally be anything. I think you need to narrow it down.

Comment: "Thoroughly" is an adverb.  "Thoroughness" is the corresponding adjective.

Comment: From a comment under one of the question: *"Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm looking for a particular word."* This site is not meant to read your mind. It shouldn't be used to throw out random darts until we come across a word you're thinking of. Unless you can give specific criteria for a specific word, the question won't be sufficiently defined.

Answer (score 5):

Not exactly what you've asked for, but you could try either "it was demonstrated conclusively that her methods were ineffective" or "it was shown conclusively that her methods were ineffective".

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm looking for a particular word.

Comment: @gladpalpitations — Why do you wish to force yourself self into a structure that is clearly not the best way to communicate your idea?

Comment: @David The word has a very particular meaning that I'm not sure I can convey as succinctly with any other word.

Comment: @gladpalpitations - Can you describe what that particular meaning is?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest "with great [finality](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/finality)."

> 1 a : the character or condition of being final, settled, irrevocable,
>   or complete
>
> b : the condition of being at an ultimate point especially of
>   development or authority

Answer (score 2):

Can you switch your word order?

> It was *thoroughly* proven that her methods were ineffective.
>
> It was *exhaustively* proven that her methods were ineffective.
>
> It was *rigorously* proven that...
>
> It was *unequivocally* proven that...

Or keeping your current word order, perhaps:

> It was proven *with great rigor* that...
> It was proven *unequivocally* that...

Answer (score 2):

Having a look at the [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) - I have a suspicion the word you are looking for is *Certainty*.

While there are not many entries, *certainty* is the only recurring phrasing linked to *proven with* and to me is a fairly common construct expressing what you describe.

> proven with statistical certainty are uncommon
>
> proven with absolute certainty

In your sample,

> It was proven with great certainty that her methods were inneffective

Comment: And what value of p do you regard as statistical certainty?  (But apologies for not noticing your answer. My certitude is just a posh-sounding variant.)

Answer (score 1):

**Credibility**

[Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/credibility):

> If someone or *something* has credibility, people believe in them and trust them.

(Emphasis mine)

[Lexico powered by Oxford](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/credibility):

> The quality of being convincing or believable.

---

In this case, you could say:

> It was proven with great credibility that her methods were ineffective

Comment: That covers the 'absence of doubt' bit, and perhaps the repetition to an extent, but it's not quite all there.

Answer (score 1):

> It was proven with great **scrupulousness** that her methods were ineffective

From Lexico (formerly Oxford Dictionaries), the example sentence seems to confirm the appropriateness of this word.

> **[Scrupulous](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/scrupulous)**
>   **1.** (of a person or process) careful, thorough, and extremely attentive to details.
>     ‘the research has been carried out with scrupulous attention to detail’
>   **Origin**
>   Late Middle English (in the sense ‘troubled with doubts’):
>   from French *scrupuleux* or Latin *scrupulosus*, from scrupulus

Answer (score 0):

*consistency* (from [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/consistency), 2019):

> Reliability or uniformity; the quality of being consistent.

Comment: It fits the sentence, but its not the word I'm looking for. Can't really be used in the sense of demonstrating publicly that something is true, or to excess.

Comment: @gladpalpitations *Proven with great consistency* would mean it is replicable right? You're right about not being proven in excess though. How about *with overwhelming support*?

Comment: it kind of works but I'm looking for a single word here.

Answer (score 0):

If it was proven repeatedly, perhaps *[resonance](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/resonance)*.

> 'It was proven with great resonance that her methods were ineffective.'

Answer (score 0):

If you enter "proven with great *" into Google Scholar, you will see "proven with great" collocates with success/certainty/detail.

Answer (score 0):

If you must tie yourself in a straightjacket, how about **certitude**?

> It was proven with great *certitude*…

Definition from Google’s unattributed steal:

> **certitude**
>
> *noun*  1. absolute certainty or conviction that something is the case.
>
> "the question may never be answered with certitude"

That example clinched it, I think, but the whole thing is a bit of an oxymoron — it is proven or not, just as one is pregnant or not.